Two way ancova violation: Do I have to include significant interaction term?
I am currently analyzing the data for my master thesis and would love to get some help.
We used a cross-over Design with follow-up measurement to determine the effects of sprints on cognitive flexibility.
Initially I wanted to run a anova with group (1 or 2) and time (t1,t2,t3) as factors and data of cognitive flexibility as dependent variable. In case of a significant interaction between group and time I would run post-hoc tests. But I detected differences in the first measurement so I have been advised to calculate an ANCOVA instead, including the data of the dependent variable at t1 as a covariate in the model which would look like this (Factors: Group and Time, Covariate:Baseline data of DV)
In the assumptions for the ancova I saw that when running a two way ancova I have to check homogenity of regression slopes of the covariate with the two factors. I read that you can  do this by running a first model checking the interactions between group and covariate and time and covariate and including the significant interaction terms in the final model. I have checked the first model and found no significant interaction for group:covariate but a significant interaction for time:covariate. Should I include the time:covariate in my final model now, like this? Factors (group, time, baseline data of dv, group:time, baseline data of dv:time)
Or is it enough to just include the baseline data of the dv as a covariate and check the group:time interaction?

ANCOVA is just a particular form of a linear multiple regression model. There's no reason to limit your analysis to specific rules classically associated with ANCOVA.
If you have enough data then it's typically best to include all interactions that might be associated with outcome in your model. As Frank Harrell says in Section 4.3 of Regression Modeling Strategies:

It is not logical that a population regression coefficient would be exactly zero just because its estimate was "insignificant."

You model will best describe your results if you include all interactions that might be expected to be associated with outcome. In R, if you used a term time * baselineCovariate * group in a linear model, that would include individual coefficients for those 3 predictors, the 2-way interactions that you examined, the interaction between time and group classically evaluated by ANCOVA, and a 3-way interaction that would allow for the association between time and baselineCovariate to differ between groups.
You also could model the continuous baselineCovariate flexibly, for example with a regression spline, instead of assuming a strictly linear association with later covariate values.
Chapters 4 and 7 of Regression Modeling Strategies are particularly relevant to your study. Chapter 4 outlines general strategies. Chapter 7 discusses ways to deal with the within-individual correlations in longitudinal data like yours; your study might be suitable for analysis via generalized least squares, as described in that Chapter.
After the full model is done, then you can examine model predictions that are related to the hypotheses underlying your study. Don't rely simply on the individual regression coefficients. What matters, when interactions are present, is how combinations of them are associated with outcome. In R, Frank Harrell's rms package and Russ Lenth's emmeans package provide useful tools for such post-modeling analysis.
